# How to add calculated column based on values in rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a calculated column based on values in rows.

My data look like:

```
df.head(5)

CountryCode question_code   answer  percentage
0   Austria b1_a    Very widespread 8
1   Austria b1_a    Fairly widespread   34
2   Austria b1_a    Fairly rare 45
3   Austria b1_a    Very rare   9
4   Austria b1_a    Don`t know  4
```

I tried:

```
def scoring(df):
    df.answer == 'Very widespread':
        return df.percentage*(-2)
    df.answer == 'Fairly widespread':
        return df.percentage*(-1)
    df.answer == 'Fairly rare':
        return df.percentage
    df.answer == 'Very rare':
        return df.percentage*2
    df.answer == 'Don`t know':
        return 0
```

which yields:

> File "", line 3
> df.answer == 'Very widespread':
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are getting invalid syntax because you doesn't used `if/else` condition inside your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to write `if`s and `elif`s:

```
def scoring(row):
    if row.answer == "Very widespread":
        return row.percentage*(-2)
    elif row.answer == "Fairly widespread":
        return row.percentage*(-1)
    elif row.answer == "Fairly rare":
        return row.percentage
    elif row.answer == "Very rare":
        return row.percentage*2
    elif row.answer == "Don\"t know":
        return 0
```

where `df` is renamed to `row` because `apply` will pass each row to it rather than the whole frame, as you can do:

```
df["scores"] = df.apply(scoring, axis=1)
```

to get

```
>>> df

  CountryCode question_code             answer  percentage  scores
0     Austria          b1_a    Very widespread           8     -16
1     Austria          b1_a  Fairly widespread          34     -34
2     Austria          b1_a        Fairly rare          45      45
3     Austria          b1_a          Very rare           9      18
4     Austria          b1_a         Don't know           4       0
```

But better yet, we can generate a multipliers-mapping beforehand and `map` the `answer` column with it:

```
mapping = {"Very widespread": -2,
           "Fairly widespread": -1,
           "Fairly rare": 1,
           "Very rare": 2,
           "Don't know": 0}
```

After mapping the `answer`s with this, result can be multiplied with `percentage`s:

```
df["scores"] = df.answer.map(mapping).mul(df.percentage)
```

which gives the same result above.

Comment: mapping: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @StanislavJirak That could happen if  `df.percentage`'s values are not numbers but strings or lists; is that the case? Can you try `df["scores"] = df.answer.map(mapping).mul(df.percentage.astype(float))`?

Comment: Aydin Yeah...I thought so, for which I tries float(df.percentage) but it returns TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: I fixed that already... There was ":" within the column. Thanks a lot!